# date_format is not a recognized built-in-function name in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my date is to be displayed as follows:

```
Monday , 1 April 2013
```

But in SQL-Server shows...

> Date_format function is not a recognized built in function

Comment: Not all database engines support the same set of functions. SQL is the query **language**; what database are you using?

Comment: Sorry sir I can't get you... you want my DB name?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? E.g, Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: @MartinSmith seeing as OP isn't getting an error for `DATENAME` from the answer below, I think it's safe to assume MS SQL Server. I really wish Microsoft had come up with a better name than that.

Comment: I am using MS-SQL  Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the below query .

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, YourDateField)+','+convert(varchar, YourDateField, 106) 
FROM YourTable
```

here is the sample testcase.. [image]

OR

Use the below query

```
SELECT FORMAT(YourDateField, N'dddd","dd MMMM yyyy', 'en-US')
FROM YourTable
```

test scenario :

[image]

Comment: Hi, When I use your method following error is occured sir..."Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int."

Comment: Try with the edited code..

Comment: sorry sir, same error again..

Comment: I tried "SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (MyDateField, 'Month DD YYYY') from TableName"  first.. But I cannot add My days(that is., sunday,monday..)here.. also I got May displayed as 5ay/ December as 9ece12ber /November as Nove11ber - all other months are ok..

Comment: can you give the code used to create the function dbo.fnFormatDate.

Comment: SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (MyDateField, 'month DD YYYY') from MyTable

Comment: ben, inside the function ,there may be some codes to handle the different date formats.. make sure the format that you required is written inside that function.. also i have added the screen shot of my code .

Comment: Its Working,Thank you So much Sir...:-)

Comment: you are always welcome.. by the way..mark it as right answer.. that will increase my points.. :)

Comment: Done sir.. Thank you once again..

Comment: Sir, Can We get the above formatted date display in SQL without using the "Convert"  function..? I mean is there any other Shrunken query available? Because I want to reduce the time of execution...

Comment: use the updated script.

Comment: But, cannot..It shows the following error message " 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: which sql server version that you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Then there is no other option.. either you have to upgrade to SQL 2012 or use the script with convert function. There is no other built in way for SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: oh ok.. Thankyou.. Currently I cannot update my version..But I need to reduce the time taken for records to be executed.. as it take make my project hanged...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW, SYSDATETIME()) + ', ' + RIGHT('0' + DATENAME(DAY, SYSDATETIME()), 2) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, SYSDATETIME())+ ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, SYSDATETIME()) AS MyDate
```

Source: [Link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much..Your one also working. But previously we used this type.. Now I want shrunken one.. Thank you so much once again..

Comment: No Issues. Important is that you got the answer you wanted. :)