# Pivot Query for Attendance

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a attendance table with studentid, atDate and status columns which is saving status for only **absent** students. students with no status are considered **Present** for the date attendance is recorded.
i need to show the attendance of students. Below is my query which is successfully generating attendance records for the selected month. problem is that i am unable to generate days in selected month dynamically as each month having different number of days. plus i want to show status for **Sundays as 'S'**

```
SELECT fkStudentID, [1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],
       [10],  [11], [12], [13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],
       [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27], [28], [29],[30], [31]
FROM(
    Select 
       fkStudentID, Status, DAY(Dated) as [DayValue] 
  From tblAttendance Where Month(Dated) = Month(@Dated) and Year(Dated) = Year(@Dated) and fkClassID = 1
) AS studAttd
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Status)
    FOR [DayValue] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],
       [10],  [11], [12], [13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],
       [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27], [28], [29],[30], [31])
) AS pvt
```

[Here is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hxBm.png)

My Desired output if a value is null it should be replaced with status 'P' and if a day is Sunday it should be replaced with status 'S' also the number of days should be generated according to selected month of date.

Comment: What is your question here? You've stated whatvyou want but not asked anytjing. For what your trying to do, have a look at `ISNULL` and the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Ali Kazmi  Can't this be done through dynamic sql?

Comment: @Tony Mathew Any Solution would be help full either it is dynamic or non dynamic :)

Answer (score 0):

My idea was:

- Find out the dates of the month
- Form a variable (@DaySelector) to select the columns; this includes logic where Sundays should have value 'P'
- Apply the above variable into a dynamic query with PIVOT

Below is a query to prove it (tempdb). I have assumed your table as a temp table '#tblAttendance'. There are two absences in the sample data, Student Id 1 absent on 20th April and Student Id 12 on 15th:

```
/* Your table*/
DROP TABLE #tblAttendance
CREATE TABLE #tblAttendance(fkStudentID int, Status varchar(20), Dated date)

/* The date to probe */
DECLARE @Dated AS date = '01-Apr-2019',
    @Days varchar(1000), @DaySelector varchar(2000);

/* Mock data: Student Id: 1 is absent on 20th April; Id 12 is Absent on 15th */
INSERT INTO #tblAttendance (fkStudentID, Status, Dated)
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
    (1, 'Absent', '20-Apr-2019'),
    (12, 'Absent', '15-Apr-2019')

) AS V1(fkStudentID, Status, Dated)

/* Fetch the days of the month */
SELECT @Days = COALESCE(@Days + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(CAST(Number + 1 AS VARCHAR(5))),

        -- Form a column selector for day's values; to be used in the dynamic query
        @DaySelector = COALESCE(@DaySelector + ',', '') + IIF(d.Day_Name = 'Sunday', 
            '''S'' AS ' + QUOTENAME(CAST(Number + 1 AS VARCHAR(5))),                                                            -- Value 'S' for Sundays        
            'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(CAST(Number + 1 AS VARCHAR(5))) + ', ''P'') AS ' + QUOTENAME(CAST(Number + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)))  -- 'P' for NULLs
        )
FROM master..spt_values
CROSS APPLY (

    -- Find out day names
    SELECT DATENAME(weekday, CAST(YEAR(@Dated) AS varchar(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(@Dated) AS varchar(2)), 2) + RIGHT('00' + CAST([number] + 1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)) AS Day_Name
    ) AS d
WHERE type = 'P'
AND
(CAST(CAST(YEAR(@Dated) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(@Dated) AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + Number)
<
DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(CAST(YEAR(@Dated) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(@Dated) AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME))

/* Prepare dynamic SQL */
DECLARE @SQL AS nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 
    'WITH PIVOT_DATA AS (' +
        'SELECT fkStudentID, ' + @Days + ' ' +

        'FROM('+
            'SELECT '+
               'fkStudentID, Status, DAY(Dated) as [DayValue] '+
          'From #tblAttendance Where MONTH(Dated) = MONTH(@Dated) and YEAR(Dated) = YEAR(@Dated)'+
        ') AS studAttd '+
        'PIVOT'+
        '('+
            'MAX(Status)'+
            'FOR [DayValue] IN (' + @Days + ')'+
        ') AS pvt' +
    ')' +
    ' SELECT fkStudentID, ' + @DaySelector + ' FROM PIVOT_DATA'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL, @params = N'@Dated date, @Days varchar(1000)', @Dated = @Dated, @Days = @Days
```

*Note:- I have excluded your condition "fkClassID = 1" for brevity*

Comment: Error while executing sql script 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: Ms Sql server 2008 R2 can you please set convert function instead of format as convert is supported. I am trying to do it with convert but still no luck.

Comment: Couldn't get hold of a 2008 server. I assume it will work with CAST. Can you try the updated code?

Comment: can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071279/date-format-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name-in-sql -- Day funcaiton can be used instead of Datename

Comment: can't see updated code format funciton is still in the code at this line - Find out day names
    --SELECT FORMAT(CAST('04-' + CAST([ ======= Sorry my bad

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. === Which version of sql you are testing on?